# PHP echo this if condition

Tags: php, arrays, string, if-statement, echo

I have some files named like: `fileONE-13` and `fileFive-22` etc.  I am trying make a php code that does the following: if whatever before the last `-` = `fileONE-`, then echo something, and if whatever before the last `-` = `fileFive-`, then echo something else.. etc.

However what I have so far just echos the first one only, even if the `bookname` is different.

```
<?php
$filename = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$chapterNo = substr(strrchr($filename, "-"), 1, 2); 
$bookname = substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, '-'));


if      ($bookname = "fileONE-") { echo "This is File 1 - $chapterNo"; }
elseif  ($bookname = "fileFive-") { echo "This is File 5 - $chapterNo"; }
?>
```

I also tried with `$bookname == "fileONE-"` ect. but it did nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you coming from VB? :) In PHP and others you test with == not = 
So what you did so far is assign "fileONE-" to  variable $bookname. so basically

```
 if ("fileONE-") { //code }
```

Which is true. Make these changes:

```
if      ($bookname == "fileONE-") { echo "This is File 1 - $chapterNo"; }
elseif  ($bookname == "fileFive-") { echo "This is File 5 - $chapterNo"; }
```

Comment: I tried with `$bookname == "fileONE-"` but it does nothing.

Comment: You need to find out what value $bookname actually has. Your code didn't work before, when it showed a false positive.

Answer (score 1):

Given your example "fileONE-13", `strrpos($filename, '-')` returns `7`, so when you set `$bookname` you're essentially saying "get the first 7 characters from `$filename` starting at position 0". That is to say, it won't include the `-` that you're checking against in the `if` statements.

PHP also uses `==`, not `=` for comparisons. As siggi_pop already pointed out, `if ($bookname = "fileONE-")` will *always* return `true` as you are reassigning `$bookname`.

Your if statements should be something like this:

```php
if      ($bookname == "fileONE") { echo "This is File 1 - $chapterNo"; }
elseif  ($bookname == "fileFive") { echo "This is File 5 - $chapterNo"; }
```